# Synchronize local CouchDB database with remote CouchDB database when connecting to the internet

Tags: django, mongodb, couchdb, offline, database-replication

The idea is simple, I don't know how the execution is:

I have a local application (Python / Django) that writes to a database (CouchDB).
The local database should be synchronized whenever possible with the remote database.
The connection to the remote database is greatly reduced, so it is important that this web page works locally on the user's computer.

Is there a way to make a synchronization between the local and the remote when the connection is available? Are there tools for that?

Important notes:

The database does not have to be exactly CouchDB, it can be another one (if there is a better one for that purpose)
As I am not developing a mobile application, I will not use a PouchDB, for example. In fact, it is an offline application, but from the web, installed on the user's computer.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Your question is still not quite clear. By default CouchDB continuous replication will reconnect when the connection is dropped. Are you looking for something else? If so, why? What problem are you facing?

Comment: My question is as follows:

If customer A has a local database A, customer B has a database B, and there is a masterdatabase. If client A (without remote connection to the master database) makes an insert in the choudb, when it comes back to the internet will it be automatically synchronized?
What if customer B entered something and was online, and that replicated to the master database at the time, when customer A goes online, will he receive this data? This applies to other operations as well, of course.

Comment: In short: there are several databases that are always synchronized when there is internet or synchronized in a master db (which will be used to initialize the data of a new client).